# Hypothesis-testing on low frequency data

Tags: hypothesis-testing

I'm trying to figure out a smart way to test some data, and afterwards correct my assumption. So I'm looking for suggestions to which path to take.

I'm looking at how often birds crash into windows, and I have a complex model with many covariates describing the crash frequency of these birds. I have data on 10,000 birds over 10 years (2002-2011). All the birds crashing into these windows survive, and I'm able to follow each bird through time (post 2011). As the bird grows older the crash frequency decreases, I assume because the birds grow more experienced. Now, I know that I'm not able to account for all the variance in my data, so I wish to construct a rating system which I apply to each bird, thus adjusting my initially calculated crash frequency after each birds individual crash history (after 2011, when my model is made).

My problem is that the birds crash very seldom, with a year as a unit, crash frequencies vary between 0.15 - 0.25. And they may even crash multiple times a year.

[image: birds]

Crash frequency from my complex model, at year 2012 is in parenthesis. Crash frequency goes down 0.02 each year, because the bird becomes one year older. All other covariates are the same, city, country, buildings etc.

Would there be a smart test, or some Bayesian approach, or some other technique to solve my problem? Kalman filter?

**EDIT**: Example:
In 2012 I make my model on 10,000 birds, 10 years of data. I get a priori estimates for all the birds, from Poisson regression. Note that I'm talking about a priori in not the regular sense, because I have 10 years of data, but I wish to update the crash frequency estimate each year, to get a "a posteriori" estimate. More explicitly:
I enter 2012, and I see results for each bird. This would maybe be too early to say anything certain regarding my a priori estimates - if they were too high or too low. But then 2013 comes, and I see new results. If some bird has crashed two years in a row, I might want to update his estimate. I would like some algorithm, model, or test, to check this each year...

**EDIT 2**: Is this a credibility theory problem, maybe?

Answer (score 0):

For rare events, if you have a lot more data, you might try Poisson regression, for which the bird-time (person-time) of follow-up is known for each bird, along with the failure event (0,1) of crashing.  Calendar year could be a variable as well as other experimental (categorical factors).  Otherwise, like you say, contingency table testing would probably work, and be certain to use the Fisher exact test (p-value).

Comment: I already have a complex Poisson regression model to get the initial crash frequency. Was this what you meant? What I want is to somehow update my initial crash frequency. How would I use a contingency table test?

Comment: Ok, since you have repeated measurements and need a chi-square type test, the best approach would be to use GEE regression (generalized estimating equations) for which you can specify a Logistic dependent variable (binary outcome).  GEE can essentially perform linear regression, logistic, and Poisson, but with repeated measurements.

Comment: I did not know what I had was repeated measurments. A priori frequencies above are calculated beforehand (say <2012 data), and the example table are meant to be data afterwards. And I do not necessarily need a chi-square type test :)

Comment: "As the bird grows older the crash frequency decreases" -- these repeated measurements on a single bird are correlated, so the analysis needs to take within-bird correlation of outcomes into consideration.  This is called longitudinal analysis of repeated measurements, specifically what GEE is for.

Comment: Your right, a year is pretty far apart, but the data are still correlated.  GLM should work if you can specify Poisson outcomes.

Comment: How would I perform Poisson regression two times?
One to make my a priori crash frequency, and one time afterwards?
I don't get it
In 2011 I make my model, I get a priori estimates for all the birds, from Poisson regression
Now I enter 2012, and I see results for each bird. This would maybe be too early to say anything certain regarding my a priori estimates - if they were too high or too low. But then 2013 comes, and I see new results. If some bird has crashed two years in a row, I might want to update his estimate. How would a GLM regression help me with this?

Comment: You have to cluster on bird ID values during the GEE (GLM) regression.  Use year as a covariate in the model -- and it's regression coef shouLd be negative if crash rates decrease with time.  caveats: if the original set of crash data include events maybe from multiple years prior, then that's an issue. Otherwise if the first year only includes crashes in that 1st year, you're OK.

Comment: Just find out in your software package how to "cluster on patient ID" during GLM regression analysis.   You should also specify a Poisson link function in GLM (GEE).  This type of analysis is called panel data -- so if you're not sure search on GLM (GEE) regression with "panel data."

Comment: Maybe I'm not seeing the point here, but I do not think you capture the essence of what I'm trying to do. I can treat these observations as independent, and what I want to do is create some rating system to calibrate my initial model as years pass.

Comment: Ok, then just do an analysis for each dataset, assuming that results will be biased if multiple repeated measurements are taken on each bird, and the analysis does not take within-bird correlation of results into consideration.  You'll have to "pay the piper" later during paper review if you make the independence assumption now, and accept the fact later after review that each bird's annual measurements are correlated.

Comment: You can always assume that since time interval is so long between crashes that the independence assumption is appropriate.  Objects "don't look like themselves" if the time between measurements is long -- this is called compound symmetry.

Answer (score 0):

So for each bird, the model is a Poisson process, where the lambda parameter is different for different birds?

In that case I suggest that you assume a suitable prior distribution for lambda, and then make a Bayesian fit to the observations to deduce a posterior distribution of lambda for each bird. The likelihood of the observations given these posterior distributions is then the quality indicator for the model.

For choosing a prior, first use a naive estimate of lambda for each bird. Then look at the empirical distribution of these. Then identify a distribution that fits it. If a gamma distribution is a reasonable fit then all the better because this is the conjugate prior for Poisson.

Only a Bayesian approach is really justifiable with sparse data. OK, assuming a prior distribution is a big assumption, but at least it is explicit. Any fit to sparse data involves prior knowledge.

Comment: I have already made a complex GLM-model to assign a crash frequency for each bird, using 10 years of data, before 2012. I have many birds, so this model is good. But I assume there are *some* unexplained variance left, that would only be captured properly if I make some sort of rating system, such that I could use each individual birds result (>=2012) and correct the frequency accordingly, like some sort of Kalman filter.

Comment: Made things hopefully a little bit more clear in the Q